# Comparing values in range

Tags: python

Have two variables 'wins' and 'clicks' with values ranging from `1` to `100K` each.

Need to flag when 'wins' are in multiples of 150, and when 'clicks' are 0 or 1?

Requirement: Iteratively want to increment both the values

```
 if 150<=int(wins)<=300 and 0<=int(clicks)<=1:
```

Comment: Could you provide example input and output? Are `wins` and `clicks` lists of values? Should `flags` be a list of booleans?

Comment: voting to delete as it is not useful Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Need to `flag` when "wins are in multiples of 150" and when "clicks are `0` OR `1`"

Try

```
flag = (clicks in (0, 1) and (wins % 150) == 0)
```

- `clicks in (0, 1)`: means clicks is either 0 or 1
- `(wins % 150) == 0`: means  `wins % 150` remainder is zero, so win is divisible by 150.

Check following:

```
>>> clicks, wins = 0, 150 * 7
>>> flag = (clicks in (0, 1) and (wins % 150) == 0)
>>> flag
True
>>> clicks, wins = 2, 150 * 7
>>> flag = (clicks in (0, 1) and (wins % 150) == 0)
>>> flag
False
>>>
```

Note: if 'clicks' and 'winds' are *strings*, then you need to use typecase `int(clicks)`, `int(wins)`. In my answer both winds and clicks are int.

---

**Edit:** I tried to make sense of your comments and question. May be with above answer following will help you:

> comment-1: Data type is int for wins and clicks:

If `wins` and `clicks` are `int` values you don't need to use typecase. Simply do as I am doing above in my answer.

> comment-2: I want to simply retrieve the records with say `150` `wins` and `clicks = 0`:

Implementing this logic is very simple:

```
if winds == 150 and clicks == 0:
  # code to retrieve record
```

Last:

> comment-3: Increment `wins` counter in multiples for `150` (should retrieve records when `wins` is in between `150-300` and `clicks = 0`)
>    4) While incrementing `wins` counter I also need to increment `clicks` counter to retrieve records
>
> e.g. when wins=[300-450] and clicks=1 retreive,
>        wins=[300-450] and clicks = 2 skip

Hard to understand! Still I believe you need something like:

```
# `num` until you wants to execute 
for _ in range(0, num):
  if clicks in (0, 1) and (wins % 150) == 0:
     # code to retrieve record
  wins += 150
```

I don't know why you increments clicks, if you only wants to retrieve records for clicks value 0, 1.

Comment: data type is int for wins and clicks

Comment: @user3234244 I posted my answer for 'int' datatypes, check examples also

Comment: The parentheses (except the pair around the `(0,1)` tuple) are unnecessary, thanks to Python's order of operations. Otherwise a good answer!

Comment: * Data type is int for wins and clicks   
1) I want to simply retreive the records with say 150 wins and clicks=0
2) Increment wins counter in multiples for 150 (should retrive records when wins is in between 150-300 and clicks =0)
3) While incrementing wins counter I also need to increment clicks counter to retreive records e.g.
   when wins=[300-450] and clicks=1 retreive
        wins=[300-450] and clicks=2 skip

Comment: @Blckknght you are correct.

Comment: @user3234244 I tried to understand your comment but I couldn't.

Comment: @user3234244 What is `"when wins=[300-450] and clicks=1 retreive wins=[300-450] and clicks=2 skip"`

Comment: @user3234244 please *edit your question* with examples of the input you have, the output you want and the code you have written so far.

Comment: @jonrsharpe still examples in comments are confusing, I tried to make some sense and updated answer, Still votes question for close as "unclear asking"